# Elixir - do nothing under particular case condition

Tags: elixir

In a `case` statement in Elixir, is it possible to do nothing if a particular condition is met in a `case` statement? Or must something always be returned?

To illustrate, here's a snippet from a Phoenix app that I'm working on:

```
Enum.map(record_params, fn(record_id) ->
    record = Repo.get!(Record, record_id)
    case Repo.update(record) do
        {:ok, struct} ->
            # I DON'T REALLY NEED ANYTHING TO HAPPEN HERE... BUT I HAVE TO HAVE A CLAUSE TO MATCH WHEN THE UPDATE RETURNS {:ok, struct}
            IO.inspect struct
        {:error, changeset} ->
            errors = parse_errors(changeset)
            IO.inspect errors
            json(conn |> put_status(400), %{status: "error", message: "There was a problem updating this record.", errors: errors})
                end
end)
```

If the `record` is updated, I need to know if there's an error, get information about it, and return that to the client, hence the need for the `case` statement... but I don't really need to do anything if the record has been updated successfully - `{:ok, struct}`.  Since these updates are taking place inside an `Enum.map()`, if the update is successful, I just want the map to continue to loop through the `record_ids`.

For the time being, I've just been putting `IO.inspect struct` in the success condition - this is harmless, but not really necessary.  I'd prefer to clean up my code, if possible.  I can't remove the `{:ok, struct}` condition due to Elixir's pattern matching, and if I put nothing at all under that condition, I get the error `syntax error before: '->'`.

Now I am totally new to Elixir (and the functional programming paradigm, in general), so if there is a more 'Elixirish' way to handle this sort of scenario, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Does this even work? You're potentially calling `json` multiple times here. Also, how are you handling the response for when all updates succeed?

Comment: You're right, this is problematic. This success response comes later on, after some other code executes - I left it out because it didn't seem germane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you're potentially calling `json` multiple times on the same `conn` in case there are multiple `Repo.update` errors. You need to stop processing the rest of the list in that case. Also, since you're not actually detecting when there are any errors, you're probably unconditionally calling `json` again later on the same `conn`. If you look at your logs, you should see that Phoenix is writing a response to the same `conn` multiple times, e.g.

```
[debug] Processing by MyApp.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 130µs
[info] Sent 200 in 232µs
[info] Sent 200 in 498µs
[info] Sent 200 in 390µs
[info] Sent 200 in 182µs
```

Here's how I'd do this with `Enum.reduce_while/3`:

```
errors = Enum.reduce_while(record_params, nil, fn(record_id, nil) ->
  record = Repo.get!(Record, record_id)
  case Repo.update(record) do
    {:ok, struct} ->
      {:cont, nil}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      errors = parse_errors(changeset)
      {:halt, errors}
  end
end)

if errors do
  json(conn |> put_status(400), %{status: "error", message: "There was a problem updating this record.", errors: errors})
else
  json(conn, "no errors!")
end
```

Comment: That is really cool - you're right, the way I had this set up was definitely incorrect, that could potentially call `json` multiple times. Thank you so much, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 21):

Despite there is already a bunch of answers, I would post another one. The idiomatic Elixir way of *ignoring all but one return* would be to use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1):

```
with {:error, changeset} <- Repo.update(record) do
  # Do whatever you want here
end
```

The `do` block would be executed if and only the match happened, otherwise the non-matched RHO value (`{:ok, _}` would be directly returned.)

For the correct code performing what you wanted, please refer to @Dogbert’s answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer for others looking specifically for the title of this question.

Answer (score 3):

The Erlang convention inherited by Elixir is to just use `:ok` as with the output of `IO.puts`

There is no allocation overhead returning an atom, since they are all interned by the runtime.

Comment: Thank you - that is really helpful. +1

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, because you are only wanting to do something for one branch, you could just use `if/2`.

```
{status, changeset} = Repo.update(record)
if status == :error do
  # Do whatever you want here
end
```

If you need to match on multiple things, you would want to use the case and just return something for that branch. In your case above, I would return `:ok`, because the action was successful.

Comment: These are all good answers, but I'm choosing this because it is really the best solution to my particular scenario.  Thank you!  I was considering using an `if` statement, but couldn't figure out how to get the returned values. Putting the outcome on the lefthand side does the trick.

Comment: `==` won't work here unless you for some reason already have a `changeset` value with you that is identical to what `Repo.update` will return and `=` won't either with `if` as it'll raise a `MatchError` if the pattern fails to match.

Comment: Good catch, you will still need to assign the changeset to something. Let me make a quick edit.

Comment: Still wouldn't work unless `Repo.update(record)` returns a default Changeset.

Answer (score 2):

Every Elixir function returns the value of the last evaluated statement. If you don't want to return anything from a function whose return value won't be used anyway, you can just add `nil` to cases where nothing needs to be returned.

```
Enum.map(record_params, fn(record_id) ->
    record = Repo.get!(Record, record_id)
    case Repo.update(record) do
        {:ok, struct} ->
            nil
        {:error, changeset} ->
            errors = parse_errors(changeset)
            IO.inspect errors
            json(conn |> put_status(400), %{status: "error", message: "There was a problem updating this record.", errors: errors})
                end
end)
```

Comment: This is mostly right, but [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) actually returns the thing you pass into it.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is really helpful.  I'm actually going to go with the suggestion about using an `if` statement since that concisely wraps up the issue I was having, but this is a great answer. +1

Comment: Glad to help! :)